# Unable to compile python3.7 on centos 5 with sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, centos, python-3.7, centos5

When am trying to compile python3.7.1 on centos 5 got the error,

```
Failed to build these modules:
_sqlite3
```

On further checking on the compile log and found the below lines,

```
building '_sqlite3' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite
/usr/bin/gcc44 -pthread -fPIC -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DMODULE_NAME="sqlite3" -IModules/_sqlite -I/usr/include -I./Include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Include -I/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1 -c /usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite/cache.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite/cache.o
/usr/bin/gcc44 -pthread -fPIC -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DMODULE_NAME="sqlite3" -IModules/_sqlite -I/usr/include -I./Include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Include -I/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1 -c /usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite/connection.o
/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c: In function ‘_pysqlite_connection_begin’:
/usr/local/src/Python-3.7.1/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c:387: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_prepare_v2’
```

Am using `/usr/bin/gcc44` along with `sqlite-devel` package is installed. I would like to know if any other faced such issue while compiling python from source and if any solution available for this compile issue.

Comment: Does python include it's own copy of sqlite, or does it use a system provided library? If the latter, what version of sqlite is installed?

Comment: Here are the sqlite rpm's installed on my machine `|sqlite|3.3.6|7|x86_64|
|python-sqlite|1.1.7|1.2.1|x86_64|
|sqlite-devel|3.3.6|7|x86_64|
|sqlite|3.3.6|7|i386|`

Comment: Wow. That version of sqlite is... really old. It predates the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` function. If python is trying to build against that, no wonder it's failing.

Comment: @Shawn Yes you are right. Just now compiled the latest version of sqlite and python is compiled now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was sqlite version was very old. I had to compile the latest sqlite3 and then compile the python3.7 which went fine.